# BroadcastReceiver is not called after createChooser(context,intent,IntentSender) is executed

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, android-broadcastreceiver, android-intent-chooser

I want to detect what app the user selects after I present him with a **createChooser()** dialog. So I have created my `BroadcastReceiver` subclass like this:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class ShareBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("INFORMATION", "Received intent after selection: "+intent.getExtras().toString());
    }
}
```

Also I have added my receiver to my android **manifest** file:

```
<application>
...
...
...
    <receiver android:name=".helpers.ShareBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="true"/>
</application>
```

And here is the code that is calling the **createChooser** dialog:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
sendIntent.setType("image/png");

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
    Log.d("INFORMATION", "The current android version allow us to know what app is chosen by the user.");

    Intent receiverIntent = new Intent(this,ShareBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, receiverIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    sendIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,"Share via...", pendingIntent.getIntentSender());
}
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Even though this is an explicit `PendingIntent` because I am using the `ShareBroadcastReceiver` class name directly without any`intent-filter`, my broadcast receiver is not being callback right after the user clicks on the chooser dialog, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything is alright in your code. You only need to change one line in `onReceive` method in your `ShareBroadcastReceiver` to catch the "EXTRA_CHOSEN_COMPONENT" key of your Intent:

`Log.d("INFORMATION", "Received intent after selection: "+intent.getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_CHOSEN_COMPONENT));`

In your log you will see something like this (in my case I chose Google Keep):

```
ComponentInfo{com.google.android.keep/com.google.android.keep.activities.ShareReceiverActivity}
```