# Android standard app chooser created by Intent.createChooser(Intent target, CharSequence title, IntentSender sender) lags

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcastreceiver

An app starts Android standard app chooser created by `Intent.createChooser(Intent target, CharSequence title, IntentSender sender)`. On Nexus 6 and Nexus 6p with Nougat it often lags:

- all items are without icons, just labels, icons are displayed later with a long delay;
- items are poorly responsive;
- the calling application receives calls about picked in the chooser item to it's BroadcastReceiver receives with a very long delay (2-5 minutes).

Devices are not busy with some heavy work.`BroadcastReceiver` is implemented in the following way it's discussed here: [BroadcastReceiver is not called after createChooser(context,intent,IntentSender) is executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39406073/broadcastreceiver-is-not-called-after-createchoosercontext-intent-intentsender)

Any ideas what could cause these issues from time to time?